# Vue.js - Two components of the same kind won't toggle properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have two components inside the template of another component that are toggled depending on the click on a "reply" and "edit" button.

```
<comment-form :model="model" :model-id="modelId" :comment="comment" v-if="showEditForm && canComment" @closeForm="closeForm"></comment-form>
<comment-form :model="model" :model-id="modelId" :parent-id="comment.id" :reply-to="comment" v-if="showReplyForm && canComment" @closeForm="closeForm"></comment-form>
```

The issue is now that it never closes the first opened instance for whatever reason. When I click "edit" and  then "reply" it seems that the instance of the "edit" stays open instead of closing it and opening the "reply" instance.

These are the methods that toggle the display of the forms:

```
methods: {
    closeForm: function () {
        this.showReplyForm = false;
        this.showEditForm = false;
    },
    reply: function () {
        this.showReplyForm = true;
        this.showEditForm = false;
    },
    editComment: function () {
        this.showEditForm = true;
        this.showReplyForm = false;
    },
},
```

**I would like to understand the reason for that behavior and how to fix it.**

Here is the whole `comment.vue` file:

```
<template>
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="header">
            <div v-if="!comment.user">
                <span class="name">{{comment.name}}</span>
                wrote on
                <span class="time">{{comment.created}}</span>:
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <span class="name">{{comment.user.username}}</span> wrote on {{comment.created}}:
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <template v-for="line in comment.body.split('\n')">{{line}}<br></template>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <a href="#" class="reply-btn" v-on:click.prevent="reply()" v-if="!isLoginRequired || isLoggedIn">
                reply
            </a>
            <span v-if="isMyComment">
                &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
                <a href="#" class="edit-btn" v-on:click.prevent="editComment()">
                    edit
                </a>
                &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
                <a href="#" class="delete-btn" v-on:click.prevent="deleteComment()">
                    delete
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <comment-form :model="model" :model-id="modelId" :comment="comment" v-if="showEditForm && canComment" @closeForm="closeForm"></comment-form>
        <comment-form :model="model" :model-id="modelId" :parent-id="comment.id" :reply-to="comment" v-if="showReplyForm && canComment" @closeForm="closeForm"></comment-form>
        <comments-list :level="level + 1" v-if="hasChildren" :model="model" :model-id="modelId" :parent-id="comment.id"></comments-list>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        comment: null,
        modelId: null,
        level: null,
        parentId: null,
        model: {
            type: String,
            default: null
        },
    },
    computed: {
        hasChildren: function() {
            return this.$commentsStore.getters.hasChildren(
                this.model,
                this.modelId,
                this.comment.id,
            );
        },
        canComment: function() {
            return this.$commentsStore.getters.canPost;
        },
        isLoggedIn: function() {
            return this.$commentsStore.getters.isLoggedIn;
        },
        isMyComment: function () {
            return this.$commentsStore.getters.isMyComment(this.comment);
        },
        isLoginRequired: function() {
            return this.$commentsStore.getters.getConfig('loginRequired');
        }
    },
    methods: {
        closeForm: function () {
            this.showReplyForm = false;
            this.showEditForm = false;
        },
        reply: function () {
            this.showReplyForm = true;
            this.showEditForm = false;
        },
        editComment: function () {
            this.showEditForm = true;
            this.showReplyForm = false;
        },
        deleteComment: function () {
            return this.$commentsStore.dispatch('deleteComment', this.comment);
        }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            showReplyForm: false,
            showEditForm: false
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the code where `reply` and `editComment` methods are triggered?

Comment: Updated the question with the whole code as it is at this moment. You can find the whole project as well on Github https://github.com/burzum/vue-comments

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `<comment-form :model="model" :model-id="modelId" :comment="comment" v-if="showEditForm && canComment" @closeForm="closeForm"></comment-form>` is the component that does not close despite you slocing it in the UI. This must mean that the variable `showEditForm` is true. The only place I can see this variable being set to true is in `editComment`. So, if I were you I would monitor this method. Log everytime it is called and see if it is called when it shouldnt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of crazy, but you need a [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key). This is the first example I've seen where you need one outside of a `v-for`.

What's going on is that you have the same component in two `v-if`s. When Vue goes to update, it sees that it's supposed to have a `comment-form`, and it already does. It doesn't recognize the differences. I'd call it a bug in Vue, tbh, but the workaround is to provide a `key` to each component instance.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showEditForm: true,
    showReplyForm: false
  },
  components: {
    commentForm: {
        methods: {
        close() {
            this.$emit('close-form');
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeForm: function() {
      this.showReplyForm = false;
      this.showEditForm = false;
    },
    reply: function() {
      this.showReplyForm = true;
      this.showEditForm = false;
    },
    editComment: function() {
      this.showEditForm = true;
      this.showReplyForm = false;
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="reply">
    Reply
  </button>
  <button @click="editComment">
    Edit
  </button>
  <comment-form v-if="showEditForm" key="edit" @close-form="closeForm" inline-template>
    <div>
      This is the edit form
      <button @click="close">
        Close it
      </button>
    </div>
  </comment-form>
  <comment-form id="reply" key="reply" v-if="showReplyForm" @close-form="closeForm" inline-template>
    <div>
      This is the reply form
      <button @click="close">
        Close it
      </button>
    </div>
  </comment-form>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that was quick! :) Thanks a lot. I've been aware of the key in v-for, now that you mention it, it's pretty logical that I need it in this case here as well. Spent half a day on debugging this simple thing!